# Pandas: return the occurrences of the most frequent value for each group (possibly without apply)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's assume the input dataset:

```
test1 = [[0,7,50], [0,3,51], [0,3,45], [1,5,50],[1,0,50],[2,6,50]]
df_test = pd.DataFrame(test1, columns=['A','B','C'])
```

that corresponds to:

```
    A   B   C
0   0   7   50
1   0   3   51
2   0   3   45
3   1   5   50
4   1   0   50
5   2   6   50
```

I would like to obtain the a dataset grouped by 'A', together with the most common value for 'B' in each group, and the occurrences of that value:

```
A   most_freq freq
0   3          2
1   5          1
2   6          1
```

I can obtain the first 2 columns with:

```
grouped = df_test.groupby("A")
out_df = pd.DataFrame(index=grouped.groups.keys())
out_df['most_freq'] = df_test.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
```

but I am having problems the last column.
Also: is there a faster way that doesn't involve 'apply'? This solution doesn't scale well with lager inputs (I also tried dask).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) which sorting by default, so then add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for top values after [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df_test.groupby('A')['B']
             .value_counts()
             .rename_axis(['A','most_freq'])
             .reset_index(name='freq')
             .drop_duplicates('A'))
print (df)
   A  most_freq  freq
0  0          3     2
2  1          0     1
4  2          6     1
```